# Filtering the data of the pie chart

Tags: php, laravel

So my problem is I am not getting the right data from the database
[image: Database]

I want to filter the data of the pie chart based on the units and show the status. For example, I selected "All Units" it will show all the status of each asset. If I applied the filter `<option value="Asset Management and Inventory Control Office">Asset Management and Inventory Control Office</option>` it will only show the status of assets inside that filter. The pie chart doesn't returns the correct data. Can you please help me I am just a newbie and trying to learn. Solutions with explanations are highly appreciated.

DashboardController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $unitFilter = $request->input('unit');

        $assetStatusQuery = DB::table('asset');

        // Apply unit filter only if a specific unit is selected
        if ($unitFilter !== null) {
            $assetStatusQuery->where('unit', $unitFilter);
        }

        // Get counts for each status
        $condemnedCount = $assetStatusQuery->when(true, function ($query) {
            $query->where('status', 'condemned');
        })->count();

        $maintenanceCount = $assetStatusQuery->when(true, function ($query) {
            $query->where('status', 'maintenance');
        })->count();

        $borrowedCount = $assetStatusQuery->when(true, function ($query) {
            $query->where('status', 'borrowed');
        })->count();

        $calibrationCount = $assetStatusQuery->when(true, function ($query) {
            $query->where('status', 'calibration');
        })->count();

        // Debugging: Output counts for each status
        echo "Condemned Count: $condemnedCount\n";
        echo "Maintenance Count: $maintenanceCount\n";
        echo "Borrowed Count: $borrowedCount\n";
        echo "Calibration Count: $calibrationCount\n";

        dd($assetStatusQuery->toSql());

        return view('admin.dash', compact('condemnedCount', 'maintenanceCount', 'borrowedCount', 'calibrationCount'));
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Log or handle the exception as needed
        return response()->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
    }
}
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('admin/dash', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('admin/dash');
```

I tried different approaches. the code that I provided is the updated code the the dd($assetStatusQuery->toSql()) returns this

[image: dd($assetStatusQuery->toSql())]